# Compile latex from python

Tags: python, compiler-construction, latex

I have made some python function for compiling passed string as *pdf* file using latex. The function works as expected and has been quite useful, therefore I look for ways to improve it.

The code which I have:

```
def generate_pdf(pdfname,table):
    """
    Generates the pdf from string
    """
    import subprocess
    import os

    f = open('cover.tex','w')
    tex = standalone_latex(table)   
    f.write(tex)
    f.close()

    proc=subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex','cover.tex'])
    subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex',tex])
    proc.communicate()
    os.unlink('cover.tex')
    os.unlink('cover.log')
    os.unlink('cover.aux')
    os.rename('cover.pdf',pdfname)
```

The problem with the code is that it creates bunch of files named *cover* in the working directory which afterwards are removed.

How to avoid of creating unneeded files at the working directory?

## Solution

```
def generate_pdf(pdfname,tex):
"""
Genertates the pdf from string
"""
import subprocess
import os
import tempfile
import shutil

current = os.getcwd()
temp = tempfile.mkdtemp()
os.chdir(temp)

f = open('cover.tex','w')
f.write(tex)
f.close()

proc=subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex','cover.tex'])
subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex',tex])
proc.communicate()

os.rename('cover.pdf',pdfname)
shutil.copy(pdfname,current)
shutil.rmtree(temp)
```

Comment: you could build your pdf in a flder you create, move out the pdf once you're done and delete the folder recursively.

Comment: These files are not unneeded, they are used by ``latex``. You can't not create them, you can only remove them afterwards as you do now (or run the process with the current directory pointed to ``tempfile.mkdtemp()``).

Comment: Those files are required for `LaTeX` to operate. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files) on TEX.SX

Comment: I would like to see the solution with *some virtual directory*.

Comment: See the [`fs`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fs) module for one way to create an in-memory file system.

Comment: @JānisErdmanis why do you run `subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex','cover.tex'])` and afterwards `subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex',tex])`?

Comment: I no longer can understand Python code at such level as I used to. It is also possible that the python APIs had improved over the last 7 years and perhaps this is no longer a recommended way of doing things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a temporary directory. Temporary directories are always writable and can be cleared by the operating system after a restart. `tempfile` library lets you create temporary files and directories in a secure way.

```
path_to_temporary_directory = tempfile.mkdtemp()
# work on the temporary directory
# ...
# move the necessary files to the destination
shutil.move(source, destination)
# delete the temporary directory (recommended)
shutil.rmtree(path_to_temporary_directory)
```

Comment: Seems a good start. How the moving to the destination is done?

Comment: Take a look at the `shutil` library. I've included the relevant calls in the answer.